# Scala3 "as" and "with" keywords used with "given"

Tags: scala, syntax, implicit, scala-3, given

Currently learning about Scala 3 implicits but I'm having a hard time grasping what the ​`as` and `with` keywords do in a definition like this:

```
given listOrdering[A](using ord: Ordering[A]) as Ordering[List[A]] with
 ​def compare(a: List[A], b: List[A]) = ...
```

I tried googeling around but didn't really find any good explanation. I've checked the Scala 3 reference guide, but the only thing I've found for `as` is that it is a "soft modifier" but that doesn't really help me understand what it does... I'm guessing that `as` in the code above is somehow used for clarifying that `listOrdering[A]` is an `Ordering[List[A]]` (like there's some kind of typing or type casting going on?), but it would be great to find the true meaning behind it.

As for `with`, I've only used it in Scala 2 to inherit multiple traits (`class A extends B with C with D`) but in the code above, it seems to be used in a different way...

Any explanation or pointing me in the right direction where to look documentation-wise is much appreciated!

Also, how would the code above look if written in Scala 2? Maybe that would help me figure out what's going on...

Comment: Where did you find the `given ... as ...` syntax? I'm somehow struggling to find any mention of it anywhere?

Comment: Neither [the documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/givens.html) nor the artima book mentions it.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I'm taking the Coursera course Functional Programming Design in Scala, and there I encountered this syntax but unfortunately the "as" and "with" keywords weren't explained. The course uses Scala 3.

Comment: This is syntax that was experimented with in the past but is not part of Scala 3. If that's really in the Coursera course you may want to report that to the maintainer of that course.

Comment: @Jasper-M that would explain why I couldn't find anything about it in the official Scala 3 documentation (although the documentation is still in progress, so there was no way for me to figure this out myself...). Just to be extra clear, are you referring to the `as` keyword in the syntax as experimental? I.e. `given ... with ...` is part of Scala 3 but `given ... as ... with` is not?

Comment: @greenTea Yes AFAIK `given ... as ... with:` does not exist. Specifically the `as` and the `:` after `with`.

Comment: Sorry, the `:` after `with` is totally a typo. Removed from the original post now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `as`-keyword seems to be some artifact from earlier Dotty versions; It's not used in Scala 3. The currently valid syntax would be:

```
given listOrdering[A](using ord: Ordering[A]): Ordering[List[A]] with
 ​ def compare(a: List[A], b: List[A]) = ???
```

The [Scala Book](https://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_5ed) gives the following rationale for the usage of `with` keyword in `given`-declarations:

> Because it is common to define an anonymous instance of a trait or class to the right of the equals sign when declaring an alias given, Scala offers a shorthand syntax that replaces the equals sign and the "new ClassName" portion of the alias given with just the keyword `with`.

i.e.

```
given foobar[X, Y, Z]: ClassName[X, Y, Z] = new ClassName[X, Y, Z]:
  def doSomething(x: X, y: Y): Z = ???
```

becomes

```
given foobar[X, Y, Z]: ClassName[X, Y, Z] with
  def doSomething(x: X, y: Y): Z = ???
```

The choice of the `with` keyword seems of no particular importance: it's simply some keyword that was already reserved, and that sounded more or less natural in this context. I guess that it's supposed to sound somewhat similar to the natural language phrases like

> "... **given** a monoid structure on integers **with** `a • b = a * b` and `e = 1` ..."

This usage of `with` is specific to `given`-declarations, and does not generalize to any other contexts. The [language reference](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/givens.html#syntax) shows that the `with`-keyword appears as a terminal symbol on the right hand side of the `StructuralInstance` production rule, i.e. this syntactic construct cannot be broken down into smaller constituent pieces that would still have the `with` keyword.

---

I believe that understanding the forces that shape the syntax is much more important than the actual syntax itself, so I'll instead describe how it arises from ordinary method definitions.

#### Step 0: Assume that we need instances of some typeclass `Foo`

Let's start with the assumption that we have recognized some common pattern, and named it `Foo`. Something like this:

```
trait Foo[X]:
  def bar: X
  def foo(a: X, b: X): X
```

#### Step 1: Create instances of `Foo` where we need them.

Now, assuming that we have some method `f` that requires a `Foo[Int]`...

```
def f[A](xs: List[A])(foo: Foo[A]): A = xs.foldLeft(foo.bar)(foo.foo)
```

... we could write down an instance of `Foo` every time we need it:

```
f(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4)))(new Foo[List[Int]] {
  def foo(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]) = a ++ b
  def bar: List[Int] = Nil
})
```

- Acting force: Need for instances of `Foo`
- Solution: Defining instances of `Foo` exactly where we need them

#### Step 2: Methods

Writing down the methods `foo` and `bar` on every invocation of `f` will very quickly become very boring and repetitive, so let's at least extract it into a method:

```
def listFoo[A]: Foo[List[A]] = new Foo[List[A]] {
  def foo(a: List[A], b: List[A]): List[A] = a ++ b
  def bar: List[A] = Nil
}
```

Now we don't have to redefine `foo` and `bar` every time we need to invoke `f`; Instead, we can simply invoke `listFoo`:

```
f(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4)))(listFoo[Int])
```

- Acting force: We don't want to write down implementations of `Foo` repeatedly
- Solution: extract the implementation into a helper method

#### Step 3: `using`

In situations where there is basically just one canonical `Foo[A]` for every `A`, passing arguments such as `listFoo[Int]` explicitly quickly becomes tiresome too, so instead, we declare `listFoo` to be a `given`, and make the `foo`-parameter of `f` implicit by adding `using`:

```
def f[A](xs: List[A])(using foo: Foo[A]): A = xs.foldLeft(foo.bar)(foo.foo)

given listFoo[A]: Foo[List[A]] = new Foo[List[A]] {
  def foo(a: List[A], b: List[A]): List[A] = a ++ b
  def bar: List[A] = Nil
}
```

Now we don't have to invoke `listFoo` every time we call `f`, because instances of `Foo` are generated automatically:

```
f(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4)))
```

- Acting force: Repeatedly supplying obvious canonical arguments is tiresome
- Solution: make them implicit, let the compiler find the right instances automatically

#### Step 4: Deduplicate type declarations

The `given listFoo[A]: Foo[List[A]] = new Foo[List[A]] {` looks kinda silly, because we have to specify the `Foo[List[A]]`-part twice. Instead, we can use `with`:

```
given listFoo[A]: Foo[List[A]] with
  def foo(a: List[A], b: List[A]): List[A] = a ++ b
  def bar: List[A] = Nil
```

Now, there is at least no duplication in the type.

- Acting force: The syntax `given xyz: SomeTrait = new SomeTrait { }` is noisy, and contains duplicated parts
- Solution: Use `with`-syntax, avoid duplication

#### Step 5: irrelevant names

Since `listFoo` is invoked by the compiler automatically, we don't really need the name, because we never use it anyway. The compiler can generate some synthetic name itself:

```
given [A]: Foo[List[A]] with
  def foo(a: List[A], b: List[A]): List[A] = a ++ b
  def bar: List[A] = Nil
```

- Acting force: specifying irrelevant names that aren't used by humans anyway is tiresome
- Solution: omit the name of the `given`s where they aren't needed.

#### All together

In the end of the process, our example is transformed into something like

```
trait Foo[X]:
  def foo(a: X, b: X): X
  def bar: X

def f[A](xs: List[A])(using foo: Foo[A]): A = xs.foldLeft(foo.bar)(foo.foo)

given [A]: Foo[List[A]] with
  def foo(a: List[A], b: List[A]): List[A] = a ++ b
  def bar: List[A] = Nil


f(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4)))
```

- There is no repetitive definition of `foo`/`bar` methods for `List`s.
- There is no need to pass the `given`s explicitly, the compiler does this for us.
- There is no duplicated type in the `given` definition
- There is no need to invent irrelevant names for methods that are not intended for humans.

Comment: Thanks for a very nice summary of the reasoning behind the syntax. However, my question was specifically about the keywords and what they mean in this particular context. And I still don't really get that from your explanation. From what you wrote, it seems that `A with { def foo= ... }` is just syntactic sugar for `trait B { def foo; }; A = new B { def foo = ...}` But does `with` only work like this when `A` is a `given`? Is this described somewhere in the documentation? And the `as` keyword still puzzles me...

Comment: @greenTea Updated. I think you're trying to interpret too much into it. It's really just a reserved keyword: it's only purpose is to separate the code to the left of it from the code to the right of it.